# Difference between Calculus $4$th edition and Calculus $3$rd edition by Michael Spivak?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I currently possess Calculus $3$rd edition by Michael Spivak in it's electronic form. However, I am considering buying a hard copy and have the option of buying either a used $3$rd edition or a new $4$th edition.

Since, the $4$th edition is quite costly for me, I want to be absolutely sure before buying. I haven't been able to locate an electronic copy of the $4th$ edition anywhere.

So, would someone be kind enough to tell me precisely the differences between the two books.

I expect to solve a good amount of hard calculus problems so I would choose whichever has more problems.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was faced with the same dilemma, I decided to go with the 3rd as the 4th is quite expensive and from what i've read online there doesn't seem to be too much of a difference between the two in terms of new material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have both 3rd edition and 4th Edition.

"Suggested Reading" is completely different between 3rd edition and 4th edition.
Except "Suggested Reading", I think there is almost no difference between 3rd edition and 4th edition.

I think 4th Edition is superior to 3rd Edition about the quality of paper.

For example, 4th edition is thinner than 3rd edition.

Michael Spivak wrote the following in "PREFACE TO THE FOURTH EDITION":

**"Although small changes have been made to some material, especially in Chapter 5 and 20, this edition differs mainly in the introduction of additional problems, a complete update of the Suggested Reading, and the correction of numerous errors."**